# get parameter changing url?

Tags: php, forms, get

I am trying to send a form via get.My point is to reopen the same page,     just with another value.
So i am at the page.

```
index.php?url=category
```

at the site i have a form with the.

```
action="index.php?url=category"
```

in the form i have a select with the

```
name="food".
```

Now i want the page URL to be like

```
index.php?url=category&food=1
```

What should insert at the action value to get to this url?
Whatever i try, it changes the url to

```
index.php?food=1
```

Comment: any reason not to use href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting a form that has method="get" will override any existing query string with the form values.

The solution is simple: Put the value into a hidden form field, then it will be submitted with the rest of them:

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="category">
```

Comment: thats a very cool idea,  i would never have come up with this idea. Thx will try it soon